# I am a senior citizen from India wish to travel three or more Schengen countries by train. What are the documents needed to get tourist visa?

Tags: schengen, indian-citizens

My wife and I from India (both are aged above 60) wish to travel by train to France, Germany, Belgium and Holland in near future. In each country, we would stay almost same number of days.

Where should we apply for tourist visa? What documents to be produced? Is it necessary that the first port of entry (from India) and the final port of departure  (to India) should be same?

Comment: Have you done any research? What did you find out?

Comment: Why you selected e-visas tag?

Answer (score 5):

According to schengen visa rules, you should apply where you would be staying maximum number of days. If you are spending equal number of days in schengen countries, then you will have to apply where you will be entering first.
In your case France is your first port of entry, so obviously you can only apply through France.

From India you can enter into France and exit through Netherlands without any difficulty. So first port of entry and final port of departure can be different.

For the required documents, you can contact embassy/ consulate or VFS(visa facilitation service) in your city in India. They should provide you all the required documents checklist